# DIAN NIT Error al consumir servicio Factura Electronica

Tags: php, xml, webservice, soap

Estoy subiendo una factura a la entidad tributaria DIAN en Colombia y en un principio tenia detalles sobre elementos faltantes en el XML, despuesde pulir esta parte ahora el webservice Soap de la DIAN me retorna el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Parametros [ NIT=ERROR DOCNUMBER=OK ISSUEDATE=OK ]

El Request que genero es...

> Por obvias razones he rellenado el NIT real con "x", asi como otros
>   elementos de seguridad del Soap-Header.
>
> Ya he verificado a detalle:
>
> 1. Que el NIT Emisor este bien escrito y sea el correcto.
> 2. Que el NIT del Emisor exista en la DIAN (use el de Persona Juridica).
> 3. Que el NIT Receptor sea distinto al emisor.
> 4. Que el NIT Receptor Exista en la DIAN (use el de Persona Natural).
> 5. Estoy haciendo las peticiones al WebService de Prueba (habilitación) de la DIAN.

```
<soapenv:envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rep="http://www.dian.gov.co/servicios/facturaelectronica/ReportarFactura">
    <soapenv:header>
        <wsse:security soapenv:mustunderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:usernametoken wsu:id="UsernameToken-2">
                <wsse:username>3bxxxxxx-7xxx-4xxx-bxxx-39xxxxxxxxxx</wsse:username>
                <wsse:password type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile1.0#PasswordText">1d97....ae</wsse:password>
                <wsse:nonce encodingtype="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security1.0#Base64Binary">bW...MQ==</wsse:nonce>
                <wsu:created>2019-03-04T22:19:11.000Z</wsu:created>
            </wsse:usernametoken>
        </wsse:security>
    </soapenv:header>
    <soapenv:body>
        <rep:enviofacturaelectronicapeticion>
            <rep:nit>901xxxxxx</rep:nit>
            <rep:invoicenumber>PRUE980000000</rep:invoicenumber>
            <rep:issuedate>2019-03-04T22:19:11</rep:issuedate>
            <rep:document>UEsD....FbXBhcw==</rep:document>
        </rep:enviofacturaelectronicapeticion>
    </soapenv:body>
</soapenv:envelope>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Después de **3 días** (que parecieron semanas jejejeje), ha quedado resuelto !.

Misma historia "la DIAN nunca respondió mis correos ni llamadas", termine resolviéndolo a punta de picar piedra y tratar cosas que hasta no tenían nada que ver con el mensaje de error.

Esta resolución sin duda es una de las mas "tontas" e interesantes porque deja a toda luz que la Entidad Tributaria DIAN en Colombia tiene mucho camino por recorrer en materia de Factura Electrónica, específicamente en la parte del "Debugeo" de la información que recibe su webservice, sin duda **esto es un reto enorme** para todo desarrollador que quiera integrar su software a Factura Electrónica.

La resolución fue: **No uses palabra acentuadas en los contenidos de los argumentos en ninguna etiqueta**

Un ejemplo:

**Error:**

```
<fe:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cbc:AdditionalAccountID>1</cbc:AdditionalAccountID>
    <fe:Party>
    <cac:PartyIdentification>
        <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)" schemeID="31">900123123</cbc:ID>
    </cac:PartyIdentification>
```

**Exito:**

```
<fe:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cbc:AdditionalAccountID>1</cbc:AdditionalAccountID>
    <fe:Party>
    <cac:PartyIdentification>
        <cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Direccion de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)" schemeID="31">900123123</cbc:ID>
    </cac:PartyIdentification>
```

Esto es tan estúpido, pero va ahorrarte días en lidiar con mensajes que no tienen absolutamente nada que ver con los mensajes de error que arroja la entidad tributaria DIAN en Colombia.

Lo mas triste, chistoso o torpe, ya nose como mencionarlo, es que la entidad tributaria DIAN en Colombia ya saco un **Kit de desarrollo** con una versión **2.0** del estándar UBL "modificado", por lo cual creo que es **demasiado inmaduro** querer pensar en migrar a otro estándar cuando el actual no lo pueden tener bien pulido. Suerte!

Comment: Lo mismo me paso a mi compañero, EL XML no puede contener tildes en los atributos pero si en los valores, opino lo mismo del nivel de inmadurez de la DIAN con respecto a la fase1 de facturación electrónica, ahora nos debemos adaptar a la fase 2. Y esta la veo toda una galleta (Requiere mucho tiempo y esfuerzo para su implementación).

Comment: @CristianGomezRuiz afirmativo, por mi parte ya estoy en el ambiente Habilitacion de Factura v2, y al dia de hoy solo se pueden enviar facturas, aun el WS tiene problemas para procesar NC y ND.

Comment: @moneyBox te hago una pequeña pregunta, ¿como vas respecto al proceso de facturación electrónica?, dado que apenas me estoy embarcando en este tema y son muchas cosas nuevas (para mi experiencia). Gracias.

Comment: @jecorrales Aprobado como Habilitado ya !.... nivel Ultrainstinto !

Comment: @moneyBox de pronto puedes colaborarme?

Comment: @jecorrales claro si quieres mandame correo a: siegroupmx [a] gmail com